# Setting up (negative?) midi delay in ableton

Tags: ableton-live, latency

When tapping a simple beat on my MPD24 controller in Ableton Live on a Macbook, the notes sound fine when I play them, but as the clip repeats, they seem to play too early. I must admit I am an utter amateur, but it seems like Ableton has moved the notes a bit earlier (to compensate for latency?).

[image: Notes just before the beat]

Perhaps there is something wrong with my brain, but I really think I am playing these notes on the beat, not before. There is also a notable difference between when I play them and when the clip repeats after that.

What setting controls this behavior? Is there a MIDI latency setup step that I skipped?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences, the click on the MIDI/Sync tab.

Open up one of your MIDI ports, and you will see the MIDI Clock Sync Delay.

Mess with that.

[image: Ableton MIDI settings]

If that doesn't do it, then Driver Error Compensation, under Latency in the Audio tab.

[image: Ableton Audio settings]

Comment: Just to verify that this *is* the switch; if I set the MIDI clock sync delay to some ridiculous value, my notes should be way off, no? This doesn't happen.